# in CSS how to remove empty space of relative position

Tags: html, css

I am creating sample page nav bar, here i wanted to keep my SVG as fixed position. for that I am using psotion: relative. my svg is placed fixed but other elements are misplaced. I wanted to remove that div class='brandname_titlebg' empty space. Please find below screen shot and CSS code.

screen shot
[image]

CSS code

```
@media screen and (max-width: 417px) {
    .brandname_titlebg svg{
        position: relative;
        margin: 0px -75px 4px;
    }
```

React js HTML code:

```
<header className='toolbar'>
            <nav className='toolbar_navigation'>
                <div className='toolbar_toggle-button'>
                    <DrawerToggleButton click={props.drawerClickHandler} />
                </div>
                <div className='brand_block'>
                    <img className='brand_img' src='https://static.wixstatic.com/media/5ec12c_d513f9b08f734b06a80202f06add857d~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_60,h_52,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/22d37318-7165-48f0-9394-f0df1c695a54.webp' alt='/images/Natrawly_logo.png'></img>
                    <h2 className='brand_tag-linestyling'>preserve the wellness of health</h2>
                    <span className='toolbar_logo'>
                        <a href='/'> naturawly </a>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div className='brandname_titlebg'>
                    <svg preserveAspectRatio='xMidYMid meet'
                        xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                        width='200'
                        height='200'
                        viewBox='24 20 152 160'
                        role='img'
                    >
                        <g>
                            <path d='M142.383 100c0 23.436-18.976 42.434-42.383 42.434-23.407 0-42.383-18.998-42.383-42.434 0-23.436 18.976-42.434 42.383-42.434 23.407 0 42.383 18.998 42.383 42.434z'
                            fill='#FDCE09' color='1'
                            ></path>
                            <path d='M80.658 52.615L53.031 35.279l7.936 31.675a51.174 51.174 0 0119.691-14.339z'
                            fill='#FDCE09' color='1'
                            ></path>
                            <path d='M150.955 103.764a50.817 50.817 0 01-7.519 23.171l-.004.023L176 124.724l-25.04-20.974-.005.014z'
                            fill='#FDCE09' color='1'
                            ></path>
                            <path d='M100 48.798c4.197 0 8.263.563 12.168 1.521h.013L100 20 87.818 50.319h.013c3.906-.958 7.972-1.521 12.169-1.521z'
                            fill='#FDCE09' color='1'
                            ></path>
                            <path d='M143.432 73.045l.004.016a50.82 50.82 0 017.514 23.171l.018.02L176 75.276l-32.568-2.231z'
                            fill='#FDCE09' color='1'
                            ></path>
                            <path d='M139.038 66.956l7.932-31.679-27.628 17.337a51.285 51.285 0 0119.696 14.342z'
                            fill='#FDCE09' color='1'
                            ></path>
                            <path d='M49.045 96.238a50.873 50.873 0 017.519-23.175l.004-.018L24 75.281 49.04 96.25l.005-.012z'
                            fill='#FDCE09' color='1'
                            ></path>
                            <path d='M100 151.209c-4.205 0-8.272-.565-12.178-1.521h-.013L100 180l12.182-30.321c-3.91.965-7.976 1.53-12.182 1.53z'
                            fill='#FDCE09' color='1'
                            ></path>
                            <path d='M119.342 147.385l27.628 17.335-7.936-31.673a51.23 51.23 0 01-19.692 14.338z'
                            fill='#FDCE09' color='1'
                            ></path>
                            <path d='M56.564 126.943a50.84 50.84 0 01-7.515-23.171l-.018-.023L24 124.726l32.568 2.227-.004-.01z'
                            fill='#FDCE09' color='1'
                            ></path>
                            <path d='M60.962 133.048l-7.932 31.673 27.623-17.335a51.34 51.34 0 01-19.691-14.338z'
                            fill='#FDCE09' color='1'
                            ></path>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div className='navspacer' />
                <div className='toolbar_navigation-items'>
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
                       <li><a href='/'>Wellness Box</a></li>
                       <li><a href='/'>Cleanse Box</a></li>
                       <li><a href='/'>Agnihotra</a></li>
                       <li><a href='/'>More</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className='login_icon-spacing'>
                    <svg className='login_icon' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
                        <path d="M25 48.077c-5.924 0-11.31-2.252-15.396-5.921 2.254-5.362 7.492-8.267 15.373-8.267 7.889 0 13.139 3.044 15.408 8.418-4.084 3.659-9.471 5.77-15.385 5.77m.278-35.3c4.927 0 8.611 3.812 8.611 8.878 0 5.21-3.875 9.456-8.611 9.456s-8.611-4.246-8.611-9.456c0-5.066 3.684-8.878 8.611-8.878M25 0C11.193 0 0 11.193 0 25c0 .915.056 1.816.152 2.705.032.295.091.581.133.873.085.589.173 1.176.298 1.751.073.338.169.665.256.997.135.515.273 1.027.439 1.529.114.342.243.675.37 1.01.18.476.369.945.577 1.406.149.331.308.657.472.98.225.446.463.883.714 1.313.182.312.365.619.56.922.272.423.56.832.856 1.237.207.284.41.568.629.841.325.408.671.796 1.02 1.182.22.244.432.494.662.728.405.415.833.801 1.265 1.186.173.154.329.325.507.475l.004-.011A24.886 24.886 0 0 0 25 50a24.881 24.881 0 0 0 16.069-5.861.126.126 0 0 1 .003.01c.172-.144.324-.309.49-.458.442-.392.88-.787 1.293-1.209.228-.232.437-.479.655-.72.352-.389.701-.78 1.028-1.191.218-.272.421-.556.627-.838.297-.405.587-.816.859-1.24a26.104 26.104 0 0 0 1.748-3.216c.208-.461.398-.93.579-1.406.127-.336.256-.669.369-1.012.167-.502.305-1.014.44-1.53.087-.332.183-.659.256-.996.126-.576.214-1.164.299-1.754.042-.292.101-.577.133-.872.095-.89.152-1.791.152-2.707C50 11.193 38.807 0 25 0"/>
                    </svg>
                    <span className='login_text-position'>Log In</span>
                </div>
                <div className='cart_bag'>
                    <svg className='cart_bag-img' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version='1.1' width="36" height="40" viewBox="5.7 0 105.5 126.1" preserveAspectRatio='xMinYMax meet'>
                        <path d="M99.8 28.4c0-1.2-0.9-2-2.1-2h-15c0 3.2 0 7.6 0 8.2 0 1.5-1.2 2.6-2.6 2.9 -1.5 0.3-2.9-0.9-3.2-2.3 0-0.3 0-0.3 0-0.6 0-0.9 0-4.7 0-8.2H40.1c0 3.2 0 7.3 0 8.2 0 1.5-1.2 2.9-2.6 2.9 -1.5 0-2.9-0.9-3.2-2.3 0-0.3 0-0.3 0-0.6 0-0.6 0-5 0-8.2h-15c-1.2 0-2 0.9-2 2L8.3 124c0 1.2 0.9 2.1 2.1 2.1h96.3c1.2 0 2.1-0.9 2.1-2.1L99.8 28.4z"/>
                        <path d="M59.1 5.9c-2.9 0-2 0-2.9 0 -2 0-4.4 0.6-6.4 1.5 -3.2 1.5-5.9 4.1-7.6 7.3 -0.9 1.8-1.5 3.5-1.8 5.6 0 0.9-0.3 1.5-0.3 2.3 0 1.2 0 2.1 0 3.2 0 1.5-1.2 2.9-2.6 2.9 -1.5 0-2.9-0.9-3.2-2.3 0-0.3 0-0.3 0-0.6 0-1.2 0-2.3 0-3.5 0-3.2 0.9-6.4 2-9.4 1.2-2.3 2.6-4.7 4.7-6.4 3.2-2.9 6.7-5 11.1-5.9C53.5 0.3 55 0 56.7 0c1.5 0 2.9 0 4.4 0 2.9 0 5.6 0.6 7.9 1.8 2.6 1.2 5 2.6 6.7 4.4 3.2 3.2 5.3 6.7 6.4 11.1 0.3 1.5 0.6 3.2 0.6 4.7 0 1.2 0 2.3 0 3.2 0 1.5-1.2 2.6-2.6 2.9s-2.9-0.9-3.2-2.3c0-0.3 0-0.3 0-0.6 0-1.2 0-2.6 0-3.8 0-2.3-0.6-4.4-1.8-6.4 -1.5-3.2-4.1-5.9-7.3-7.3 -1.8-0.9-3.5-1.8-5.9-1.8C61.1 5.9 59.1 5.9 59.1 5.9L59.1 5.9z"/>
                        <text x='58.5' y='67' dy='.35em' fontSize='20' dominant-baseline="middle" textAnchor='middle'>0</text>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

full CSS code.

```
.toolbar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    border-bottom: thick solid $green-navbarline
}

.toolbar_navigation{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    align-items: center;
}

.brandname_titlebg{
    opacity: 1;
}

.brandname_titlebg svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

.brand_block{
    line-height: normal;
    justify-content: center;
}
.brand_img {
    width:60px;
    height:52px;
    object-fit:cover;
    object-position:50% 50%;
}

.brand_tag-linestyling{
    color: $yellow-brandtag;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -6px;
    left: 30px;
}

.toolbar_logo {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.toolbar_logo a{
    color: $green-brandname;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.navspacer{
    flex: 1; //it means it will take all available space
}

.toolbar_navigation-items ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.toolbar_navigation-items li{
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.toolbar_navigation-items a{
    color: $light-black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.toolbar_navigation-items a:hover,
.toolbar_navigation-items a:active {
    color: $yellow-ulitems;
}

@media (max-width: 896px) {
    .toolbar_navigation-items{
        display: none;
    }
    .brand_tag-linestyling{
        font-size: 12px;
        bottom: -6px;
        left: 80px;
    }
    .brand_block{
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .brandname_titlebg svg {
        width: 100%;
        height: 32px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: -1;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 417px) {
    .brandname_titlebg svg{
        position: relative;
        margin: 0px -75px 4px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 897px) {
    .toolbar_toggle-button{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you add html

Comment: I am creating in React js, added React js HTML code.